# Why can't I catch an async exception with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, exception, try-catch

I need catch an async exception but i can´t use async/await.

I´m trying to use promises, but it doesn´t work.

An example:

```
myAsyncFunction().then(function() {
  console.log("EVERYTHING OK");
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});

function myAsyncFunction() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    externalLibraryFunctionAsyncToApiRequest(); //this function throw error
  });
}
```

I can´t modify the externalLibraryFunctionAsynToApiRequest.

Can I do anything to catch a possible exception?

Comment: As written you can't, because `myAsyncFunction` doesn't resolve or reject the promise it creates (and it isn't `async`, so that's an odd name for it). Does `externalLibraryFunctionAsyncToApiRequest()` return a promise?

Comment: `try { externalLibraryFunction.....(); } catch (e) { reject(e); }`

Comment: `externalLibraryFunctionAsyncToApiRequest().catch( /* ... */ )` Although, if the external function already returns a promise, [there is no need to a promise constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it), just `return externalLibraryFunctionAsyncToApiRequest()` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what `externalLibraryFunctionAsyncToApiRequest` actually does. But, if you don't `resolve` or `reject` your `Promise` then nothing is going to come back regardless of success or failure.

You should do something like this:

```js
myAsyncFunction().then(function() {
  console.log("EVERYTHING OK");
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});

function myAsyncFunction() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    try {
      throw 'something happend';
      // If no error resolve();
    } catch (ex) {
      reject(ex);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: If externalLibraryFunctionAsyncToApiRequest function does an ajax call (and other things) and the ajax call can throw errors, can I catch the errors here?

Comment: Yes. That's correct assuming you're not also doing a try/catch in that function.